# JavaScript find and replace a character in between specified characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace all `[space]` with `-` between `__tt` and `tt__`

I could replace *space* in the entire string with below regex.

```js
var str = document.getElementById('tt').value;
str = str.replace(/(?<=__tt.*) (?=.*tt__)/g, '-');
console.log(str);
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="tt">This is a long text __tt where i want 
to replace
some text tt__ between some character
</textarea>
```

Is there a way I could do the replace only between `__tt` and `tt__` tag ???

Comment: Try `str = str.replace(/__tt.*?tt__/g, (m) => m.replace(/ /g, "-"));`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Awesome, It worked !!. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without lookarounds, which are not yet fully supported by all browsers you might also use a replacement using a callback function over the selected match only.

```
str = str.replace(/__tt.*?tt__/g, m => m.replace(/ /g, "-"));
```

```js
var str = 'This is a long text __tt where i want to replace some text tt__ between some character';
str = str.replace(/__tt.*?tt__/g, m => m.replace(/ /g, "-"));
console.log(str);
```

**Note**

If you want a single hyphen in the replacement for multiple consecutive spaces, you could repeat the space 1 or more times using  `+` or match 1 or more whitespace chars using `\s+`

With the updated question, get the text of the element:

```js
var elm = document.getElementById("tt");
elm.textContent = elm.textContent.replace(/__tt[^]*?tt__/g, m => m.replace(/ +/g, "-"));
```

```html
<textarea id="tt" rows="4" cols="50">This is a long text __tt where i want
to replace
some text tt__ between some character
</textarea>
```

Comment: Is it possible to replace other character instead of space ?

Comment: That depends on the use case. If you want to replace other characters for the current example, you could replace matching the space with the character that you want to match for example char `a` like `m.replace(/a/g, "-")`

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to make this solution work in **multi line** string ??

Comment: If you want to have to dot match a newline, use `str = str.replace(/__[^]*?__/g, m => m.replace(/ /g, "-"));`

Comment: Thanks for the update.. Can you please check the updated question. I want to match `__tt` not just `__`

Comment: @Pugazh Ah I forget the tt part, like `str = str.replace(/__tt[^]*?tt__/g, m => m.replace(/ /g, "-"));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210744/discussion-between-pugazh-and-the-fourth-bird).

Answer (score 3):

You could take positive look behind and look ahead.

```js
var str = 'This is a long text __tt where i want to replace some text tt__ between some character';

str = str.replace(/(?<=__tt.*) (?=.*tt__)/g, '-');

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Is it possible to replace other character instead of space ?

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to make this solution work in multi line string ??

Answer (score 1):

can try it

```js
let str = 'This is a long text __tt where i want to replace some text tt__ between some character';
str = str.replace(/__tt.*?tt__/g, (item) => item.replace(/ /g, "-"));
console.log(str);
```